# Selenium: Configure Firefox webdriver to not run in test mode

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, firefox, webdriver, automated-tests

I'm using Selenium to automate a navigation in [Google Meet website](http://meet.google.com) for a user who can't use the keyboard. However, Google Meet won't let me enter a meeting when using Chrome in test mode. If I configure Chrome webdriver to run as a regular browser, I can navigate on the website a little but eventually I can't enter a meeting at all. Here is the python code I use to initialize Chrome as a non-test browser:

```js
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://meet.google.com/some_meeting_id")
time.sleep(3)
txtName = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#jd\.anon_name')
txtName.send_keys("user_name" + Keys.RETURN) // redirects to an error page
```

My next hope is to use Firefox, but when I load it from webdriver, it opens with an orange address bar, indicating that it is being run by a test tool. Is there a way to run Firefox in normal mode from Selenium (just as I did with Chrome) or, even better, is there any additional configuration I can do in Chrome webdriver to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

May be try this to switch the headless mode on firefox to normal mode

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code opened Firefox in test mode as well.